# EOS.IO has now download link for accessing the EOS client wallet like Bitcoin Core. Or is there no such thing?

Tags: wallet

I went to eos.io looking for a download link to download the EOS blockchain and create a wallet like how Bitcoin Core works. Or does EOS doesn't work like this as its a POS system and there is no client software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wallet tool provided in the EOSIO software is called `keosd` and can be downloaded from GitHub or Docker registry together with `nodeos` (node software) and `cleos` (cli software to interact with `nodeos` and `keosd`).

[image]
*Image from [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/how-it-all-fits-together)*

To use the tools from docker, you can follow [the article in the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software). Alternatively, you can install the tools locally by cloning the GitHub repo and building the toolkit as explained [in this document](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/getting-the-code).

Once you have `cleos` and `keosd`, you can use [the wallet article in the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets) for example usage.

For a more comprehensive walk-through, the official docs detail a step-by-step process [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs).